# How will I select a particular object from the array of objects in the mongoose schema?

Tags: express, mongoose

```js
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    // schema setup
    var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        type:{
            type:String,
            required:[true,'a product must have a type']
        },
        sId:String,
        image:String,
        products:[{
            name:String,
            image:String,
            price:Number
        }]
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Product",productSchema);
```

I have made my mongoose schema like this. Now I just want to access a particular object from the array of objects named 'products' using a mongoose query.
Can anyone please tell me how can i do this?? I'll be soo grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "products.name": "name"
},
{
  "products.$": 1
})
```

With this query you will find the product object whose `name` field is 'name'. Afther that, with the positional operator `$` only the matching is returning.

Mongo playground example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tyYQJarvoE-)

Edit: Note that this query will return multiple subdocuments if exists multiple documents with the array object matching. To filter for a unique element you have to indicate another unique field like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "sId": "1",
  "products.name": "name"
},
{
  "products.$": 1
})
```

Edit to explain how to use `find` using `mongoose`.

You can use `find` or `findOne`, but the query itself will be the same.

This is pretty simple. You need to use your model described in the question, so the code is somthing like this:

```js
var objectFound = await YourModel.findOne({
  "products.name": "name"
},
{
  "products.$": 1
})
```

Where `YourModel` is the schema defined.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer.But what you told me will only work in the console.What would be the mongoose query for it..to directly add in the code???

Comment: @ShagunSharma I've updated the answer. But, basically the query itself is the same into ```mongoose```. You have to call ```findOne()``` function from your model.